# Why isn't my function outputting the list i want it to

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting, range

I want my function to output a list with ordered elements, but all it outputs is "none"

```
def sort(number):
    for i in range(len(number)-1, 0, -1):
        for x in range(i):
            if number[x]>number[x+1]:
                temp = number[x]
                number[x] = number[x+1]
                temp = number[x+1]
                return

number = [1,4,2,6,9,3,7,8,11,10]

sortednum = sort(number)
print(sortednum)
```

> OUTPUT: none

Comment: You don't actually return anything. Looks like you are implementing an in-place sort. So it shouldn't return anything, it should alter the input list (in this case `number`). Look at the [difference](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) between the python functions `list.sort` and `sorted` for a frame of reference on the difference between operating in-place and returning an entirely new list.

Answer (score 0):

You have no return statement after the outermost `for` loop, so Python implicitly returns `None`. Even in the `if` statement, you're returning `None` (because you've written `return` and not specified a value to return), so there isn't any possibility of your function returning anything other than `None`.

Edit: You're sorting the list in place too, so it doesn't make sense to return something. Either create a new list with the sorted values and return that, or if you want to sort in place, then returning `None` would be the correct thing. Don't mix the two.

Comment: I tried removing a the return statement in the `if` statement and adding a `return` statement in the outer `for` loop. But it still outputs `none` . I've even tried typing `return(sort(number))` but it still outputs `none`

Comment: Added further comments to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

python already has a sorting function [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/sort)

This is how you could implement it:

```py
number = [1, 4, 2, 6, 9, 3, 7, 8, 11, 10]

sortednum = number.copy() # Copy the list
sortednum.sort() # Sort the new list
print(sortednum)
```

I hope this helps!